# is it possible to to set a default value for input type number from a mysql table?

Tags: php, input, types, numbers

i would like to use an "input type number" to update some values on a mysql table. is it possible to set default value with the value of the table?

i tried this:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="20" value="<?php echo $row['table_value'];?>">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible, and you are on the right track. You can follow this as [reference](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/07/14/phpmysql-query/) and remember not to use mysql_* functions anymore as they already deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using it in "while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))"

```
<input type='number' min='0' max='20' maxlength='2' name='name' value='". $row['value_from_mysql'] . "'/>
```